# IOQM 2022: Problem 22 on Binary Sequence

Tags: functions, contest-math, recurrence-relations, binary

The following problem is from $IOQM, 2022$, which was held today in India. This is problem number $ 22$:

> A binary sequence is a sequence in which each term is equal to $0 $ or $ 1 $.  A binary sequence is called $friendly$ if each term is adjacent to at least one term that is equal to $1$. For example, the sequence $0, 1, 1,0,0, 1,1,1$ is friendly. Let $F_n $ denote the number of friendly binary sequences with $n$ terms. Find the smallest positive integer $n≥2 $ such that $F_n > 100$.

> MY ATTEMPT:

First, I manually counted $F_1 =1$, $F_2 = 3$, and $F_3 =5$. Now, I try to find a recurrence relation on $F_n$.

Note that if $F$ is a friendly sequence, then the last three terms in $F$ can only be

> 101, 010, 110, 111, 011

Now, consider the sequences ending with $1$, for next term can be both $0$ or $1$, hence there are two different sequences for 1 sequence ending with 1. Similarly, there is only $1$ different sequence for each sequence ending with $0.$

Now, let $F_n$ has $a$ and $b$ sequences ending with $0$ and $1$ respectively, then $F_{n+1}$ would have respectively $b$ and $a+b$ sequences ending with $0$ and $1.$

It comes out that, $$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}.$$

Is this solution correct?

Can someone please post a exact solution?

Thanks.

EDIT: I think the question does not acknowledge any sequence with $n=1$ term as friendly, that is $F_1=0$, since the last statement says $n≥2$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Surely you are able to work out $F_n$ for small $n$, for instance.  Recursions look messy at first glance, but messy is ok if we are sticking to small numbers (and $7,8$ are still quite small).

Comment: There are only $2^7 =128$ binary sequences of length $7$, so even the most naive algorithm which cycles through them and counts the friendly ones should give you an answer in milliseconds. Do you know how to write a simple computer program? (Python, C, sth else)

Comment: @Nico this question appeared in an Olympiad examination where students are obviously not allowed to use computer programming. Rest aside, I want an approach for this problem, not the final result.

Comment: Is an entry of a sequence considered to be adjacent to itself? Because if not, I would say that $F_1=0$, $F_2 = 1 (11)$, $F_3=3 (011, 110, 111)$.

Comment: @AbVk1718 Okay. I thought maybe you just want to know which experts teachers are correct.

Comment: @paw88789 Though it is not clearly mentioned in the question, in my attempt i assumed that an entry is does considered adjacent to itself, but it doesn't make sense (an entry being adjacent to itself).

Comment: @MatthewTowers  I am confused, if F is a Fibonacci sequence or Tribonacci sequence as posted by a user there.